# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry error

Tags: java, android

here's my build.gradle dependencies part :
 `

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')

compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.+'
```

and my error is : 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthException.class

what's the cause of the error ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding google-play-services twice in your gradle file.

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar') 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.+'
```

Remove the following line from your `build.gradle` file.

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

Comment: remove `google-play-services.jar` from libs directory

Answer (score 0):

you need use multidex in project [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)